# Count and agregate data by time

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, union

I'm looking for a beauty-easy to read-smart SQL query (SQLite engine) to agregate data in column. It is more easy to explain with an example :

Data table :

```
 id  elapsedtime httpcode
 1          0.0      200
 2          0.1      200
 3          0.3      301
 4          0.6      404
 5          1.0      200
 6          1.1      404
 7          1.2      500
```

Expected result set : a column by httpcode, with number of code by time. In this example, the time agregation is 0.2s (but it can be agregated at a second, or 10s). I'm interested only in some expected http_code :

```
 time code_200 code_404 code_500 code_other
 0.0        2        0        0          0
 0.2        0        0        0          1
 0.4        0        1        0          0
 0.6        0        0        0          0
 0.8        0        0        0          0
 1.0        1        1        1          0
```

It is not mandatory for "time" to be continuous. In the previous example, line with time 0.6 and 0.6 can be removed.

For the moment, I can do this by doing 4 different requests (one by http code) and I agregate the result in my developped application:

```
select
0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as code_200
from test
where (httpcode=200)
group by time
```

But i'm pretty sure i can achieve this with a single query. Unfortunally i'm not mastering UNION keyword...

Is there a way to get such data in a single SELECT ?

See SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2081f/3/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a nicer solution than my original post, which I'll leave in, in case you're curious. Here's the nicer solution:

```
with t1 as (
    select
    0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time,
    case httpcode when 200 then 1 else 0 end code_200,
    case httpcode when 404 then 1 else 0 end code_404,
    case httpcode when 500 then 1 else 0 end code_500,
    case when httpcode not in (200, 404, 500) then 1 else 0 end code_other
    from test
)

select time,
sum(code_200) as count_200,
sum(code_404) as count_404,
sum(code_500) as count_500,
sum(code_other) as count_other
from t1
group by time;
```

---

Old solution:

This might not be too easy on the eye, but it more or less works (only difference between your desired output and what I get with this is that time groupings that have no values (0.6 and 0.8 in your example) are omitted:

```
with 

t_all as (select
0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as total
from test
group by time
),

t_200 as (select
0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as code_200
from test
where (httpcode=200)
group by time),

t_404 as (select
0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as code_404
from test
where (httpcode=404)
group by time),

t_500 as (select
0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as code_500
from test
where (httpcode=500)
group by time),

t_other as (select
0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as code_other
from test
where (httpcode not in (200, 404, 500))
group by time)

select 
t_all.time,
total,
ifnull(code_200,0) as count_200,
ifnull(code_404,0) as count_404,
ifnull(code_500,0) as count_500,
ifnull(code_other,0) as count_other
from t_all
left join t_200 on t_all.time = t_200.time
left join t_404 on t_all.time = t_404.time
left join t_500 on t_all.time = t_500.time
left join t_other on t_all.time = t_other.time;
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the nicer solution. I will bench it and compare it to answer of user3551009 with a 10K row input sets.

Comment: `WITH` statement can be replaced by inluding the query in the FROM statement.

Comment: Yes, using the common table expression rather than a subquery was just personal preference here, I didn’t test to see if there were any performance differences though.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

```
select
    0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time, count(id) as code_200,
    0 as code_404,
    0 as code_500,
    0 as code_other
from
    test
where (httpcode=200)
group by time
union
select
    0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time,0 as code_200,
    count(id) as code_404,
    0 as code_500,
    0 as code_other
from
    test
where (httpcode=404)
group by time
union
select
    0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time,0 as code_200,
    0 as code_400,
    count(id) as code_500,
    0 as code_other
from
    test
where (httpcode=500)
group by time
union
select
     0.2 * cast (elapsedtime/ 0.2 as int) as time,0 as code_200,
     0 as code_400,
     0 as code_500,
     count(id) as code_other
from
  test
where (httpcode<>200 and httpcode <> 404 and httpcode <> 500)
group by time
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My last attempt resulted in such a query, with easy readability. I also like the anwser of thesilkworm (much smaller)